# Bitbucket Cloud git fetch and git pull not grabbing recent commits for a branch

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-cloud

I created a branch using Bitbucket cloud. Then I went to my two laptops and ran `git fetch` and `git checkout new-branch`. I can successfully see the new branch.

On laptop A, I make some changes commit them then I push them to the origin using following commands

`git add .

 git commit -m 'some message'

 git push -u origin new-branch`

I can see them under commits on bitbucket.org.

Then when I go to Laptop B and run `git fetch` says up to date. run `git pull`. Says already up to date. I cannot pull down the latest commits from the branch.

Go back to bitbucket.org and the commits are still listed there. If I create a new branch then go and fetch it on Laptop B using `git fetch` then if I  run `git pull` on that old branch it will now return the commits I was missing.

Has anyone had this happen before.

Comment: Can you please post the exactly commands that you are using in order to check what could be wrong?

Comment: @Dazak I formatted my post better to highlight the commands. Let me know if there is anything else I can clarify.

Comment: try in Laptop B run `git fetch --all`, then `git pull origin new-branch`

Comment: I ran both. `git fetch --all` just returned `fetching origin`. Then `git pull origin new-branch` just returned `Already up to date`. When i double checked what each branch was pointing to using `git branch -avv` and it still showed the old commit as the one the remote was pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your two working directories may be pointing to different remotes. Run this command on both and carefully compare the outputs:

```bash
$ git remote -vv
```

Assuming those are **identical**, the next thing to check is `git status` on each. It's possible that one of your working directory HEADs is in a "weird" state, and `git status` may tell you how to fix that (for example if you abandoned a rebase operation without running `git rebase --abort`).